# Hazelcast server is delaying in heartbeat and cant connect with client

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I was doing some testing with Hazelcast-3.5.1, it was working fine with 1GB heap But when heap size increased to 4GB, it works perfectly till memory use reaches around 80% later on heartbeat response delay grows rapidly. (as per the logs like - System clock apparently jumped from '' to '' since last heartbeat)

And after some time client/mancenter is not able to connect also server jvm crashes.

Platform - Ubuntu 14.04 ( 8GB )
Hazelcast - 3.5.1
Java - 1.7.0_79

Server Logs :

```
> Aug 20, 2015 5:22:07 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO:
> [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev] [3.5.1] System clock apparently jumped from
> 2015-08-20T17:21:54.376 to 2015-08-20T17:22:07.564 since last
> heartbeat (+12188ms). Aug 20, 2015 5:22:07 PM
> com.hazelcast.internal.monitors.HealthMonitor INFO: [172.17.42.1]:5701
> [dev] [3.5.1] processors=4, physical.memory.total=7.5G,
> physical.memory.free=347.9M, swap.space.total=7.7G,
> swap.space.free=7.6G, heap.memory.used=3.5G, heap.memory.free=301.1M,
> heap.memory.total=3.8G, heap.memory.max=3.8G,
> heap.memory.used/total=92.28%, heap.memory.used/max=92.28%,
> minor.gc.count=33, minor.gc.time=9148ms, major.gc.count=22,
> major.gc.time=152120ms, load.process=85.00%, load.system=95.00%,
> load.systemAverage=4.77, thread.count=54, thread.peakCount=56,
> cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=10,
> executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0,
> executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0,
> executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=10,
> executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0,
> operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0,
> operations.pending.invocations.count=0,
> operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, proxy.count=1,
> clientEndpoint.count=1, connection.active.count=1,
> client.connection.count=1, connection.count=0 Aug 20, 2015 5:22:22 PM
> com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO: [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev]
> [3.5.1] System clock apparently jumped from 2015-08-20T17:22:08.564 to
> 2015-08-20T17:22:22.467 since last heartbeat (+12903ms). Aug 20, 2015
> 6:13:59 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO:
> [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev] [3.5.1] System clock apparently jumped from
> 2015-08-20T18:10:46.846 to 2015-08-20T18:13:59.477 since last
> heartbeat (+191631ms). Aug 20, 2015 6:13:04 PM
> com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO: [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev]
> [3.5.1] System clock apparently jumped from 2015-08-20T18:10:46.846 to
> 2015-08-20T18:12:17.580 since last heartbeat (+89734ms). Aug 20, 2015
> 6:15:55 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO:
> [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev] [3.5.1] System clock apparently jumped from
> 2015-08-20T18:12:17.580 to 2015-08-20T18:15:55.876 since last
> heartbeat (+217296ms). Aug 20, 2015 6:15:55 PM
> com.hazelcast.client.ClientEndpointManager INFO: [172.17.42.1]:5701
> [dev] [3.5.1] Destroying ClientEndpoint{conn=Connection
> [0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5701 -> /127.0.0.1:59157],
> endpoint=Address[127.0.0.1]:59157, live=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT,
> principal='ClientPrincipal{uuid='d32f7c02-afb4-4212-8f1b-118c526f3e05',
> ownerUuid='be3921ba-52fa-4939-a029-6afb5013c25a'}',
> firstConnection=true, authenticated=true} Aug 20, 2015 6:12:58 PM
> com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.SocketAcceptor INFO: [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev]
> [3.5.1] Accepting socket connection from /127.0.0.1:59171 Aug 20, 2015
> 6:15:55 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO:
> [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev] [3.5.1] System clock apparently jumped from
> 2015-08-20T18:13:59.477 to 2015-08-20T18:15:55.875 since last
> heartbeat (+115398ms). Aug 20, 2015 6:15:55 PM
> com.hazelcast.internal.monitors.HealthMonitor INFO: [172.17.42.1]:5701
> [dev] [3.5.1] processors=4, physical.memory.total=7.5G,
> physical.memory.free=401.2M, swap.space.total=7.7G,
> swap.space.free=7.6G, heap.memory.used=3.6G, heap.memory.free=188.9M,
> heap.memory.total=3.8G, heap.memory.max=3.8G,
> heap.memory.used/total=95.16%, heap.memory.used/max=95.16%,
> minor.gc.count=33, minor.gc.time=9148ms, major.gc.count=515,
> major.gc.time=3369835ms, load.process=94.00%, load.system=97.00%,
> load.systemAverage=4.12, thread.count=46, thread.peakCount=67,
> cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0,
> executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0,
> executor.q.scheduled.size=3, executor.q.io.size=0,
> executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0,
> executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0,
> operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0,
> operations.pending.invocations.count=0,
> operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, proxy.count=1,
> clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0,
> client.connection.count=0, connection.count=0 Aug 20, 2015 6:15:55 PM
> com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.WriteHandler WARNING: [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev]
> [3.5.1] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-out-0 Closing socket to
> endpoint Address[127.0.0.1]:59044,
> Cause:java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
> java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException   at
> sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)     at
> sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)     at
> com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.AbstractSelectionHandler.unregisterOp(AbstractSelectionHandler.java:99)
>   at
> com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.WriteHandler.unschedule(WriteHandler.java:197)
>   at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.WriteHandler.handle(WriteHandler.java:252)
>   at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.WriteHandler.run(WriteHandler.java:331)    at
> com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.AbstractIOSelector.executeTask(AbstractIOSelector.java:104)
>   at
> com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.AbstractIOSelector.processSelectionQueue(AbstractIOSelector.java:97)
>   at
> com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.AbstractIOSelector.run(AbstractIOSelector.java:123)
> WARNING: [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev] [3.5.1] Resetting master
> confirmation timestamps because of huge system clock jump! Clock-Jump:
> 661318ms, Master-Confirmation-Timeout: 500000ms.
> #
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> #
> #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f49ba237122, pid=13165, tid=139954432919296
> #
> # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b14) (build 1.7.0_79-b14)
> # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
> # Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.6
> # Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1
> # Problematic frame:
> # V  [libjvm.so+0x82b122]  ParallelCompactData::calc_new_pointer(HeapWord*)+0x32
> #
> # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Comment: One of the question is why the heart beat message takes such a long time to get through. 

Would it be possible to reproduce the problem using Hazelcast 3.6-SNAPSHOT? I have added a internal metrics that provide very detailed information about the internals, including all the queue sizes of connections. This way we get more detailed insights in what is happening. The health monitor in 3.6 makes of the new metrics system, but only shows a fraction of the information. I can help you to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an Ubuntu issue.

I had the same issue on my old AWS-hosted para-virtual instances. The fix there was to migrate to newer HVM instances.

More info on AWS' known issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=560443